# extract data using python

Tags: python, csv, split, txt

I have a text file (abc.txt) which contains following:

```
10 20 0 #1st line
-9 -9 -9 -9 #2nd line
4 4 #3rd line
2 2 0. 0. hello #4th line
15 25 1 #5th line
-9 -9 0 1 #6th line
5 5 #7th line
7 7 8. 8. hello #8th line
```

I want to get all the data before "hello" word and save it in a csv file. which means there will be two rows based on the above data :

```
Ist row: 10 20 0 -9 -9 -9 -9 4 4 1 1 2 2
2nd row: 15 25 1 -9 -9 0 1 5 5 7 7 8 8
```

So far I tried attached code in the jpg file (of course it will just give an empty csv file)

```
with open(inputDir + "all_data.csv", "w") as output1File:
output = "";

inputFile = inputDir + fileName;

with open(inputFile, "r") as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:              
        if line.endswith(" name"):
            values = line.split(" ")
            value = values[1].strip();
            output = output + value + "\n" ;
output1File.write(output + "\n");
```

Can anyone please help me how to write this code so that I can get all_data.csv file with the above mentioned two rows? The dataset I have shown in text file is just a case study. My original file contains a lot of data but same pattern.

Thanks in advance :)

[python code that I wrote so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFWA8.png)

[abc.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vKRe.png)

P.S. I am new in Python. Just started learning.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, this is my first post here in stackoverflow.. I tried again and looks like the code is now as TEXT..

Answer (score 0):

How about just using regular expression?

```py
import re

with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text) # whitespaces (including newline) → ' '
text = re.sub(r' hello ', '\n', text) # hello → newline

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

The following might be more similar to your original code:

```py
output = ''

with open("abc.txt", "r") as f:
    temp = []
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        if values: # if the line is empty, then pass
            if values[-1] == 'hello': # if last value is 'hello'
                output += ' '.join(temp + values[:-1]) + '\n'
                temp = []
            else:
                temp += values # store this line

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output);
```

One thing to note in your original code is that `line.endswith(" name")` does not work. When you iterate over the file using `for line in inputFile:`, the variable `line` actually is a string like `'... name\n'`, i.e., it ends with `name\n`, not with `name`. So you would need to use `line.endswith(" name\n")`.